# Update fields from an array with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an array that is sent to my controller, such as this:

```
$array = array(
        [0]=>array(
             [id]=>5,
             [position]=>6 
        ),
       [1]=>array(
             [id]=>8,
             [position]=>2 
        )
);
```

And I need to save the position of each item using its id. What is the best way to do this in cakePHP? I can only imagine looping an update function or pulling the entire database, changing the correct values, then saving the database. Both ideas seem very bodged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha, Cake magic to the rescue again. You don't have to tell Cake to save it by id. There's a big long amazing way Cake does this, but the short and skinny is -

if your array contains an 'id' key, Cake presumes it is the table primary key and generates an  UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT. Looks like this:

```
UPDATE table as Table SET Table.position = $position WHERE Table.id = $id;
```

And, Cake knows to iterate for you if you use saveAll() instead of save():

```
$this->Model->saveAll($array);
```

If you have any save callbacks in your model, such as beforeSave(), you have to call them manually before calling saveAll() - they only autofire on save(), not saveAll() or updateAll().

You'll want to top your array with the name of your model ($array['Model'][0], $array['Model'][1], etc). If you need to magically saveAll() with multiple models, you top your array with indexed keys, then model names - like $array[0]['Model1'], $array[0]['Model2']) and Cake knows to save / update the associated data for all the models in each index batch.

Cake does ALL the legwork for you:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data - especially the saveAll() entry.

- Edit - and topping your array with your model name? Cake makes that ridiculously easy, too. Check out Cake's built-in Set library for all your array / object manipulation needs.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1487/Set

Comment: actually, save all takes int indexed array, not with the model name eg: $this->Article->saveAll($data['Article']); not $this->Article->saveAll($data); where the array is $data['Article'][n]['field]. The array OP pasted in the question is the correct format for saveAll, its documented in the link you pasted but you still got it wrong

Comment: @dogmatic69-- actually, I got both exactly right. :) The API is totally clear -> http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveAll - "Record data to save. This can be either a numerically-indexed array (for saving multiple records of the same type), or an array indexed by association name." API entries + redacted code examples pasted from my live app for illustration -> saveAll() **1 record + multiple models** works exactly as the API says it does :) Didn't bother pasting an example of saveAll() -> **multiple records, 1 model** because -> no need, OP's code shows that. :)

Comment: @dogmatic69-- It bears mentioning, I answered another closely-related question from the OP shortly before the OP asked this question; the first question included more context and background, and OP's code showed arrays structured a bit differently, etc. I included the extra information about cake's save / saveAll, model callbacks, etc. and examples because the additional background indicated the OP would find heavy-duty Model methods useful / relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285006/save-data-using-ajax-and-cakephp/6292513#6292513

Comment: thanks for your answer, the extra detail was appreciated. I was unsure who to award the correct answer to, since you both linked to the saveAll function which ultimately gave me the solution I was looking for. I gave Dave the correct answer as I though he answered first, but clearly you have the more detailed and useful response.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried CakePHP's `saveAll()` ?  [Details here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data).

Comment: I continually underestimate what cake can do. Of course if the data is in the correct format, cake will process it as normal... Seems so simple now!