# CakePHP: few joins, belongsTo and hasMany relations done in two queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, has-many, belongs-to

I need some help with CakePHP 2.2.3.

### What I have

I have the following setup at the moment:

`Post` **hasMany** `Attachment`

It works fine and the page is generated with 2 queries:

```
SELECT *, `Post`.`id` 
FROM `posts` AS `Post` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Post`.`created` DESC

SELECT 
    `Attachment`.`id`, 
    `Attachment`.`post_id`, 
    `Attachment`.`created` 
FROM 
    `attachments` AS `Attachment` 
WHERE 
    `Attachment`.`post_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ..., n)
```

### What I want

I want to extend the relation to be as follows:

`Post` **hasMany** `Attachment`; every `Attachment` **belongsTo** `Type`

And I don't know hot to make CakePHP follow it.
Basically, what I need is:

```
SELECT *, `Post`.`id` 
FROM `posts` AS `Post` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
ORDER BY `Post`.`created` DESC

SELECT 
    `Attachment`.`id`, 
    `Attachment`.`post_id`, 
    `Attachment`.`created`, 
    `Type`.`title`, `Type`.`icon` 
FROM 
    `attachments` AS `Attachment` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `types` AS `Type` 
    ON (`Attachment`.`type_id`=`Type`.`id`) 
WHERE 
    `Attachment`.`post_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ..., n)
```

Note the `LEFT JOIN types` added.

So I get the corresponding type data in the second query. I know I could get the data in a loop or using a `->query()` call, but I want this to be as much effective and flexible as possible.

### The problem

I tried the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), [Model Unbinding trick](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations) ([and this one](http://ask.amoeba.co.in/joining-multiple-tables-in-cakephp-using-bindmodel-method/)) but no success. I tried different combinations of the options, I believe I've even removed joins. Here's what my `PostsController` looks like now.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {

        $this->Post->unbindModel(array('hasMany' => array('Attachment')));
        $this->Post->Attachment->unbindModel(array('belongsTo' => array('Type')));

        $this->Post->bindModel(array(
            'hasMany' => array(
                'Attachment' => array(
                    'className'  => 'Attachment',
                // when uncommented, throws the "Unknown column Post.id" SQLSTATE error
                //  'conditions' => array('Post.id' => 'Attachment.post_id'),
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $this->Post->Attachment->bindModel(array(
            'belongsTo' => array(
                'Filetype' => array(
                    'className'  => 'Filetype',
                //  'conditions' => array('Type.id' => 'Attachment.type_id'),
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $all = $this->Post->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'alias' => 'User',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'User.id = Post.user_id',
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'contain' => array('Attachment', 'Type'),
            'conditions' => array(),
            'fields' => array('*'),
            'order' => 'Post.created ASC'
        ));
        var_dump($all);exit;
    }
}
```

But it just runs an extra query per each iteration in a loop and gets *all* the attachments:

```
SELECT `Attachment`.`id`, ... 
FROM `attachments` AS `Attachment` 
WHERE 1 = 1
```

When I uncomment the condition for this association, it throws me the SQLSTATE "Column Post.id not found error" - I guess because there's no Post table joined here.

I need a hand in setting this up.

Please help! Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've changed the controller as follows. Please note there's no `bindModel`/`unbindModel` code, the relation is set in the models classes (is that correct in this case?).

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $options = array(
            'contain' => array(
                'Post',
                'Type'
            ),
            'order' => 'Post.created DESC',
            'conditions' => array(
            //  'Post.title LIKE' => 'my post'
            )
        );

    //  The following throws "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object"
    //  $posts = $this->Attachment->find('all', $options); 

    //  So I had to use $this->Post->Attachment instead of $this->Attachment
        $posts = $this->Post->Attachment->find('all', $options);
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
    }   
}
```

This is the `Attachment` model:

```
class Attachment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Type' => array(
            'className' => 'Type',
            'foreignKey' => 'type_id',
        ),
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

The above code runs this query:

```
SELECT 
    `Attachment`.`id`, `Attachment`.`type_id`, `Attachment`.`post_id`, `Attachment`.`created`, 
    `Type`.`id`, `Type`.`title`, 
    `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`text`, `Post`.`created` 
FROM 
    `attachments` AS `Attachment` 
    LEFT JOIN `types` AS `Type` ON (`Attachment`.`type_id` = `Type`.`id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `posts` AS `Post` ON (`Attachment`.`post_id` = `Post`.`id`) 
WHERE 
    1 = 1 
ORDER BY 
    `Post`.`created` ASC
```

Everything is about the attachments here. I mean the posts are joined to attachments, so if the post has no attachments, it's not returned. This is probably because the call is `Attachment->find()` so it's from the attachment's point of view. I guess it just should be:

```
// ...
FROM 
    `posts` AS `Post`
    LEFT JOIN `attachments` AS `Attachment`  ON (`Attachment`.`post_id` = `Post`.`id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `types` AS `Type` ON (`Attachment`.`type_id` = `Type`.`id`) 
// ...
```

But it's not going to work, is it? You see there are `posts`, `attachments` and `types`, but they do have the *different* relation types.  Originally, I've posted those two separate queries CakePHP runs - there must be reasons for that.

**UPDATE2**

I still believe that it's all about changing the second query to the `Attachment` model in the initial setup (please see the *What I Want* section). So I will get attachments types along with attachments themselves. I mean in that case LEFT JOINing the `types` table to `attachments` is not going to break any database relation logic, is it?
I just want to make sure there's no way to do that with one complex, but single `find()` call.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Cake sees a hasMany relationship, it will automatically create multiple queries to pull the data. While constructing those queries, it looks for relationships that can be LEFT joined to it (hasOne and belongsTo).

Since Cake can't do this for you, you will need to merge them yourself.

```
public function index() {
  $posts = $this->Post->find('all');
  // get all attachments for all found posts
  $attachments = $this->Post->Attachment->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('Type'),
    'conditions' => array('Post.id' => Set::extract('/Post/id', $posts)
  ));
  // now join them to the posts array
  foreach ($posts as $key => $data) {
    $postId = $data['Post']['id'];
    // append any data related to this post to the post's array
    $posts[$key] += Set::extract("/Attachment[post_id=$postId]/..", $attachments);
  }
  $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it since you'll iterate through the `$attachments` array multiple times, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: thank you for your reply but how do I join the users table there?

Comment: Just add it to the appropriate place the `contain` array. I.e. if it belongsTo Post, then `'contain' => array('Post' => array('User'), 'Type')`

Comment: `var_dump`'d the `$posts` array. It has 20 items in it, each one with a `Post` and `Attachment` sub-array, no `Type`. Please don't get me wrong, but is this a workaround using a pagination-specific feature? I just need to somehow join the tables and get the data. Maybe I missed something with `Containable`? Thanks

Comment: I just removed the pagination references. Remember that a pagination call is just a slightly-special find call (it adds the proper limits, etc.), so most options can be used for a regular find call. I incorrectly assumed pagination, that's why you only got 20 results. This all assumes Type is related to the Attachment model already (i.e., in the relationships var or bound via bindModel).

Comment: Updated my answer. You can eliminate attachments without posts by adding a condition to eliminate null posts from the query (a left join produces null values if there's no join, so we specify in the query not to include these attachments).

Comment: I appreciate you spending your time on this. But please, note that I do not need to eliminate null posts from the query result. If the post does not have any attachments, I still need to show it. In the setup you suggest, the `attachments` is the base table, whereas I need the `posts` to be so.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, what you want to do is not possible using the ORM, unless you change Attachment from a hasMany to a hasOne relationship via bind/unbind (I can show you an example). That could produce undesired results as well, though, as it only pulls one Attachment. I'm thinking the best way to solve your problem is with two Cake find calls and merging them yourself, since Cake won't do it the way you need it done.

Comment: Having another find() call and merging the results is a good idea actually. Still better than having an extra query per each post in a loop. Please also see the question updated.

Comment: I'm just looking over this now but I'm pretty sure you can do this all in a single query. First question - have you looked at this? (Answer section #3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285006/save-data-using-ajax-and-cakephp/6292513#6292513 Granted it was written for 1.3 but should still be highly applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the finderQuery in hasMany.
Eg:
In the Post model,

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Attachment' => array(
        'className' => 'Attachment',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '                            
             SELECT 
                 `Attachment`.`id`, 
                 `Attachment`.`post_id`, 
                 `Attachment`.`created`, 
                 `Type`.`title`, 
                 `Type`.`icon` 
                  FROM 
                 `attachments` AS `Attachment` 
                  LEFT JOIN 
                 `types` AS `Type` 
                  ON (`Attachment`.`type_id`=`Type`.`id`) 
                   WHERE 
                          `Attachment`.`post_id` IN (1, 2, 3, ..., n)
                ',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
```